# Google OIDC: How to get the member_key of an external SSO user?

Tags: go, openid-connect, google-workspace

I'm develop a go application with offers SSO with Google Workspace, using OIDC/OAuth2.

While login works fine, I have no issues.

I also implement an additional check to validate, if a users is inside a specific group.

To do that, I'm using the [groups.memberships.searchDirectGroups](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups.memberships/searchDirectGroups) method from [Cloud Identity API](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest). As query, I'm using `member_key_id == 'member_key_id_value'`. For `member_key_id_value` I'm using the email, given by the email claim from the users id_token. For accessing the API, I'm using the access token from the user.

The procedure works fine for internal users. But for external users, imported via SAML sync, it wont work.

I figure out, that for external users, member_key_id isn't the email of the user. While the email is `name@CompanyA.com`, the member key is `name_CompanyA.com@CompanyB.com`.

However, the id_token nor the userinfo endpoint doesn't provide the member_key_id of a user.

Does someone have an idea, how I could use the Cloud Identity API with external users?

---

The alternative cloud be the Directory API from the Admin SDK. But I'm unable to access it.